# How compiler works in case of error: reference to ‘mytype’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, typedef, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity, name-lookup

I have created one scenario where I want help. Below code is the sample test application for same.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    typedef int mytype;
    mytype GetInt() { return 1;}
};

class B
{
public:
    typedef char mytype;
};

class C : public A, public B
{
};

class D : public C
{
public:
    void scenario()
    {
        mytype m = GetInt();
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d1;
    d1.scenario();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling code using : g++ tmp.cpp

```
Error:
tmp.cpp:27:9: error: reference to ‘mytype’ is ambiguous
         mytype m = GetInt();
         ^
tmp.cpp:15:18: note: candidates are: typedef char B::mytype
     typedef char mytype;
                  ^
tmp.cpp:8:17: note:                 typedef int A::mytype
     typedef int mytype;
                 ^
tmp.cpp:27:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘m’
         mytype m = GetInt();
```

As we can see from the code that GetInt() is defined only in the class A, so I though that mytype will be taken from class A only. But it is not the case as per the error log.

We can solve this by adding the scope of class A like

> A::mytype m = GetInt();

I want to know about: 
How compiler is behaving in this case?
Is there ant compiler flag that will solve this error in case of gcc?

Comment: You could also use type-deduction using `auto` as in `auto m = GetInt();` (if you have a compiler that handles C++11 or newer).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for another way of solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

*[dcl.typedef]/p6*

> In a given scope, a typedef specifier shall not be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that
>   scope to refer to a different type

`GetInt` might be defined in `A` but the `typedef`s in the base classes will bring the conflict into play when resolving the name in `scenario()` (cfr. *[class.member.lookup]*) since this is an unqualified lookup.

This behavior is defined and expected. I'm not aware of any flag you might use to achieve your goal. Either go for a qualified name lookup as you've already discovered or use `auto` type deduction as Joachim pointed out.